# Android, cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentpageradapter, support-v4

I wanted to program fragments for my chat but I always get the same error message. on the internet, I read that it should have to do with the "import" and the "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;" but that does not work for me.

Added the packet also in the build.gradle (app) does not work ..

My Android Studio version is 3.3 Canary 5.

I hope you can solve my problem maybe, many thanks!

**TabsPagerAdapter**

```
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                RequestsFragment requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();
                return requestsFragment;

            case 1:
                ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                return chatsFragment;

            case 2:
                FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                return friendsFragment;

            default:
                return null;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Requests";

            case 1:
                return "Chats";
            case 2:
                return "Friends";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.nexsis.entwicklung.swapv12"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {

        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28'
        implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha04'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i think you import like this way 
    import androidx.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Thank u for answer but its not work.. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/fTn5kz

Comment: remove `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28'  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28'`.

Comment: does not work.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your imports seem to collide ...

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

// this one is the old version of androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
// import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

down-grading, as other answers suggest does not appear to be the solution.
see the [artifact mappings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor), which explain how to chance the `build.gradle`; for example, `com.android.support:support-fragment` would need to be replaced there with `androidx.fragment:fragment`, so that the import would become known.

Comment: Thanks for u answere but its not working for me, Screenshot: https://ibb.co/nka0kz

Comment: @ThorstenMenzel you'd have to refactor that `RequestsFragment` as well, because it seems that this might still return `instanceof android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, which does not match the signature anymore, once having replaced the imports in the one class. this at least applies while importing, when using the full class-name, it might not complain.

Answer (score 0):

**When using getFragmentMangager(), make sure that your Fragment classes extend android.app.Fragment class.
If by any chance you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment (see your imports), then you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead**

add this in your build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

and your import should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

**instead of**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use same version for Fragment,FragmentManager,FragmentPagerAdapter

i.e.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not work, Screenshot: ibb.co/nDTpCe

Comment: Please check RequestFragment, ChatsFragment etc. all are v4.app.Fragment

Comment: In the FrendsFragment etc "import android.app.Fragment;"
When I add it to "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;" Change I get an error again

Comment: Please try to be consistent using Frgament. I mean if you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment, use it through out your app. I recommend you to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. So, you have to correct those errors.